# How do I compile the raw-cpuid crate in rust?

Tags: rust

I am using [raw-cpuid](http://gz.github.io/rust-x86/raw_cpuid/) crate for a project. It uses `raw::Slice` structure in [`processor_brand_string()` function of `ExtendedFunctionInfo structure`](http://gz.github.io/rust-x86/raw_cpuid/struct.ExtendedFunctionInfo.html#method.processor_brand_string).

```
let slice = raw::Slice { data: brand_string_start, len: 3*4*4 };
```

The above statement doesn't compile. It aborts with this error

```
cannot find struct, variant or union type `Slice` in module `raw`
   --> /home/ubuntu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/raw-cpuid-2.0.0/src/lib.rs:435:25
    |
435 |             let slice = raw::Slice { data: brand_string_start, len: 3*4 };
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `raw`
```

The crate uses `no_std` attribute. The Rust book says

> When we’re using the standard library, Rust automatically brings `std`
>   into scope, allowing you to use its features without an explicit
>   import. By the same token, when using `#![no_std]`, Rust will bring `core`
>   into scope for you, as well as its prelude. This means that a lot of
>   code will Just Work.

I checked the core crate and it has [`Slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/core/raw/struct.Slice.html) structure in the raw module. I have searched for any resolution of this error but I couldn't find one and me being new to Rust am unable to figure out what to do. I don't think many have used this crate but any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are apparently compiling `raw-cpuid 2.0.0` which is more than a year old. The version `2.0.1` released on June, the 8th 2016 compiles fine for me.

Comment: If you can use nightly Rust, you can use my [cupid crate](https://github.com/shepmaster/cupid), which is a pure-Rust implementation.

Comment: @Shepmaster `raw-cpuid` requires nightly, too AFAIK.

Comment: Also, I just released cupid 0.3.0, which now works on stable :-)